# google map multiple markers simple filtering

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have set up a Google Map with 122 markers, multiple categories (12). Can I create a filter according to the image each marker is using in order to turn on/off markers from the form?
Would it be better to define another variable as a "category" variable?
If I use JQuery, how can I restructure the code in order for it to work?

any ideas would be appreciated.

JScript looks like this:

```
function initialize() {

var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(,),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};        
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),myOptions);

var image = [];             //define an array to store category images
image['church']='icons/chapel-2.png'
image['monastery']='icons/convent-2.png'
image['archaeo']='icons/monument.png'
image['wild']='icons/wildlife.png'
image['museum']='icons/museum_openair.png'
image['beach']='icons/beach.png'
image['must']='icons/star.png'
image['summit']='icons/peak.png'
image['cave']='icons/cave-2.png'
image['forest']='icons/palmTree.png'
image['gorge']='icons/canyon-2.png'
image['village']='icons/smallcity.png'

//define 122 markers as below until var marker122 (no comments here I am trying to keep it simple..

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(,), 
         map: map,
         title: 'placeName',
         clickable: true,
         icon: image['must']
});
```

HTML Looks like this:

```
<form action="#">
Must Visit: <input type="checkbox" id="mustbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'must')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            Beaches: <input type="checkbox" id="beachbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'beach')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            Archaeology: <input type="checkbox" id="archaeobox" onclick="boxclick(this,'archaeo')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            Church: <input type="checkbox" id="religionnbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'church')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        Monastery: <input type="checkbox" id="conventbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'convent')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        Gorge: <input type="checkbox" id="gorgebox" onclick="boxclick(this,'gorge')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            Cave: <input type="checkbox" id="cavetbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'cave')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            Forest: <input type="checkbox" id="forestbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'forest')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            Wildlife: <input type="checkbox" id="wildbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'wild')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            Museum: <input type="checkbox" id="museumbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'museum')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        Villages: <input type="checkbox" id="villagebox" onclick="boxclick(this,'village')" /><br />
            Mountain Summit: <input type="checkbox" id="summitbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'summit')" /><br />
```

Comment: Also, I just found this example with a simple search, complete with jsfiddle example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682069/how-to-show-hide-google-maps-markers-by-group-and-trigger-the-event-from-un-ht

Comment: @dKen is my form in good shape?
since I have the markers stored in categorized arrays shouldn't I write within my form: onclick="boxclick(this,'ArrayName')"??

Comment: Can you add everything you have to a JSFiddle and I'll take a look? Putting it in JSFiddle means I don't have to look through code that doesn't relate to the issue, but also may help you solve the problem while you build it up too.

Comment: @dKen [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aiolosply/vxMnX/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Sorry to be a pain, but there's over 1,000 lines of code in there; can you remove all but maybe 2 categories and maybe 5 markers to show what the problem is? Your link doesn't load Google Maps either; does it load for you?

Comment: @dKen you re rigth, i have removed most of the markers. GM do not load because I cannot use the script code within JSFidle, neither HTML nor JS boxes...:(

Comment: @dKen you re rigth, i have removed most of the markers. GM do not load because I did not put the link on external sources...even though I changed it, it stil doesn't load..

Comment: @dKen this is the updated [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aiolosply/vxMnX/12/)

Comment: forget it...i can not deal with jsfidle bull** right now...thanx for your time anyway..

Comment: @dKen check this if you can http://jsfiddle.net/aiolosply/MrncS/12/

Comment: I think you're biting off more than you can chew. I couldn't even get the map going on your JSFiddle. You should've broken it down into steps: get the map going, get markers showing, toggle markers instead of doing it all at once. It was faster for me to put together an example than figure out yours. This is a simple map with only two markers and a function that toggles the markers. Create as many lists as you like and as many buttons/checkboxes as you like, and call the toggle function passing in the list you want to toggle: http://jsfiddle.net/gUumB/1/

Comment: @dKen i don't understand this:
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], myOptions);

Comment: It returns a DOM element. It's a different way of saying `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);`, but using jQuery. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @dKen its alright...right now I have completed the code but the issue here is that I need to restructure it( what starts when etc..)
I believe that is why my map is not loading at the moment. I am trying to define variables globally, and also trying to understand what to include to initialize()...

Comment: @dKen should the map initialization function include all the other functions we have or should it be separate?
because from what I see, I have the initialization() function in which there is an infowindow() as well, and a separate function toggleMarkers() at the end...the problem is the map is still not loading...:S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create filter on multiple map markers and it will work very efficiently. I have done it on my one of the project. Where there is a dropdown as filter, on selected value of dropdown filter are applied on map makers object by setting simply show and hide to its visibility property. 
To do this you have work with collection(array) in javascript.
In the beginning you add the all google markers object into the collection. When any filter is selected, then just change the property of map marker object from that collection, you can change property like visibility, image and its other property. you will see it will work very efficiently. Avoid creating new object at time of filter selected, it will bring unsmoothness to the map.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. I've done something very similar but I can't find the exact project right now. I did it by adding the markers to arrays, and looping through those arrays and showing/hiding them depending on which checkboxes are clicked.

```
// Create an array
var markersFacebook = [];

// Create a marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(,), 
     map: map,
     title: 'placeName',
     clickable: true,
     icon: image['must']
});

// Add the marker to an array of your choice. You'll have one for each category
markersFacebook.push(marker);

// Now you can show and hide your markers by looping through the array
function toggleMarkers(visible)
{
    jQuery(markersFacebook).each(function(id, marker) {
        // Hide or show the marker here depending on the state of a checkbox, or whatever you like
        marker.setVisible(visible);
    });
}

toggleMarkers(false); // This should hide all the markers
```

Sorry I couldn't give you a complete, working example, but the array approach should work for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: should I add the markers in the array one at a time or can I use something like this:
    
markersMust.push(marker, marker117, marker118, marker119, marker120,  marker121);

markersChurch.push(marker28, marker29, marker30, marker31, marker32, marker33, marker34);
or is it possible to use a continuous range where this is possible?
and regarding JQuery is something like this OK:
function toggleMarkers(visible){
jQuery(markersMust).each(function(mustbox, marker) {
marker.setVisible(visible);    marker117.setVisible(visible);    marker118.setVisible(visible);    marker121.setVisible(visible);}}

Comment: I believe I have created the arrays for my categories & stored the markers in their respective array. My problem is that the jquery doesn't seem to connect to my "checkbox" form in order to work properly.
Is there a way for you to skim through the code to see for yourself?